# Take out last 2 characters from the string and append at the beginning of the string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a requirement where from the string, I need to take out the last 2 characters and append them at the beginning of the string.

Example: **FM73457 2038** is the string value. I want to take the last 2 char i.e. 38 from FM73457 20**38** and append it to start i.e. **38**FM73457 and remove space and 20.

The output should be like   **38FM73457**

Is there another way to do it apart from concat?

```
select substr('FM73457 2038',11,2)||substr('FM73457 2038',1,7) from dual;

38FM73457
```

Comment: If the length is always the same then how you did it seems just fine. But if you don't know the length, then you could include LENGTH and RIGHT and REPLACE.

Comment: @Dan (and Isolated), this is **Oracle**; there are no LEFT nor RIGHT functions there.

Comment: Just use your query. Its going to be more efficient than using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another way to do it apart from concat?

You could use regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '^(.*) \d\d(\d\d)$', '\2\1') AS replaced
FROM   table_name;
```

But its quicker to use simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value, -2) || SUBSTR(value, 1, 7) AS replaced
FROM   table_name
```

or:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value, -2) || SUBSTR(value, 1, LENGTH(value) - 5) AS replaced
FROM   table_name
```

or:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(value, -2) || SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, ' ') - 1) AS replaced
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'FM73457 2038' FROM DUAL;
```

All output:

| REPLACED |
| --- |
| 38FM73457 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fTu15pHj)

Answer (score 1):

The way you put it (i.e. with the following sample data)

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'FM73457 2038' from dual)
```

a simple option is to literally take the last two characters and concatenate it to the 1st *word* from the input string:

```
  3  select substr(col, -2) || regexp_substr(col, '\w+') result
  4  from test;

RESULT
---------
38FM73457

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank You All for your help and giving insight into my queries